# Hard reset vs Windows Device Recovery Tool

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, reset, lumia-640

I want to reset my Windows 10 Mobile back to 8.1. I see there are 2 ways that seem to return a phone to its factory settings: a [hard reset](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10768/windows-10-mobile-reset-my-phone), and the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq). Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, they are not the same.**

> I want to reset my Windows 10 Mobile back to 8.1

In your case Windows Device Recovery tool is the only option. Here is the reason.

---

**Hard reset**

- Hard reset will not change the version of Operating system. The OS and firmware version remains the same.
- Only files, apps, settings and other data will be lost.
- In your case, the phone will remain in Windows 10 Mobile.
- It does not require any internet connectivity.

**Windows Device Recovery Tool**

- Windows Device Recovery tool on the other hand will install the latest version of Windows 10/WP8.1 (WP 8.1 for your phone).
- This tools also installs the latest version of firmware if available.
- It requires Internet connectivity.